# When you use a <br/> tag for line spacing, how many pixels are in that space (in height)?

Tags: html

## Header

How many pixels are between this sentence and the header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually default font-size of the browser is 16px.
Setting font-size: 100% will make 1rem = 16px.

Answer (score 0):

The value you are looking for is called **line-height**, it varies from browser to browser but you can set it up yourself in your CSS.

Comment: Check this [link](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/l/line-height/) out for more information on this subject

Comment: Ok, I did not know that, thank you for the information!

Comment: I shall try that

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the browser and/or device that you are using. It is not a specified amount across all browsers. However, given all of this the break tag is not intended to adjust margin or padding etc. If you want to choose the location of your text you should definitely use CSS as opposed to break tag which will give you a lot more control.